# where clause in SQL

Tags: asp.net, sql

I have dropdownlist which having records  'All','A','B','C' .

On click event of button I am fetching records from database through Stored Procedure.

My sql query which is in stored procedure :

```
Select * from TableA where Name = @Name
```

here @Name is parameter which I have passed to stored procedure whose value is selecting from dropdownlist.

If I am selecting 'A' from dropdownlist my query will be

```
Select * from TableA where Name = 'A'
```

but my question is if I am selecting 'All' then I want records like

```
Select * from TableA
```

How can I execute that in single statement of query? I dont want to use If.. else condition in stored procedure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Select * from TableA where ((@Name = 'All') OR (Name = @Name))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
select *  
from A 
where @Name = 'All' or Name = @Name
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select * from TableA where Name = @Name or @Name = 'All'
```